# How do you implement Nested CV in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, cross-validation

I would like to do nested cross validation in Spark. I am unable to find a way to do an inner GridSearchCV round and then pass that to an outer Cross Validate round as normally done in Sklearn.

I also notice that the Spark Cross Validate function allows to pass a parameter grid, which pretty much makes it identical to sklearn's GridSearchCV. So maybe I could have an inner PySpark Cross Validate function with a param_grid, and pass it to an outer PySpark Cross Validate function with no param_grid.

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Not clear to me what is it you cannot do. Maybe if you could share the `sklearn` code you normally use. With `spark_sklearn`, at least to my understanding, you can do the same kind of stuff as with "raw" `sklearn`. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "inner" and "outer"?